# Using canvas I get an blank screen trying to print header 1 and header 2 with shadows

Tags: javascript, html, css

Any help will be very much appriciated. I can't find an error in code. 
I suspect that is problem within a function doFirst. Watched tutorial on thenewboston.com, follow all instructions but can't find the cause. 
Can you see what is happening? Thanks in advance
Regards!

Javascript file:

```
function doFirst(){
var x= document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas = x.getContext('2d');
canvas.shadowOffsetX = 4;
canvas.shadowOffsetY = 4;
canvas.shadowBlur = 6;
canvas.shadowColor = 'rgba(0,0,255,.5)';
canvas.textAlign = "end";
canvas.fillText("<h1>Welcome to the Kule's web site! + "<br/>" + "<h2>Under construction...</h2>"<h1>, 300, 100);
}

window.addEventListener("load", doFirst, false);
```

Index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>

 <title>Ivan Kusakovic | Qle </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

 <script src="javascript/scripting.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body onLoad="onLoadFunkcija()" >

 <script type="text/javascript">
 var i = prompt("Enter your name: ");
 document.write(i+ ", thanks for visiting site. Play the music in the bottom of the page if you want :) ");

 function onLoadFunkcija(){
     alert('Hello guest, have a nice day!');
 }
 </script> 


 <section id="main">
   <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="300">

   </canvas>
 </section>
 <a href="SecondPage.html">Some page</a><br>
 <a href="GuestBook.html">Sign in to the guest book</a>
```

Comment: The canvas can't print HTML, only raw text. And some of your strings have broken quote marks.

Comment: Where are broken quote marks? I can't see it. 
And how to print just two lines:
Welcome to my web site, and, Under construction...
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"<h1>Welcome to the Kule's web site! + "<br/>" + "<h2>Under construction...</h2>"<h1>
```

First off, the string you're trying to print is completely broken. You didn't close it after `site!` and you closed it too soon before `<h1>`, which should be `</h1>`. And your HTML is broken too because you can't wrap an h2 inside an h1. Finally, you could write it in a single string, I don't know why you broke it up in parts.

```
"<h1>Welcome to the Kule's web site!</h1><h2>Under construction...</h2>"
```

But this doesn't matter at all because you can't print HTML in the canvas. If all you wanted was a header, just write it in HTML before the canvas.

---

If you want to draw text using the canvas, you'll have to use the style properties on the canvas context object. You can read more about [canvas style properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Applying_styles_and_colors) here and about [drawing text here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_text).

To make line breaks in a string you can normally use `\n`, but it seems the canvas doesn't support it. You'll have to call the drawing function for each line manually.

```
canvas.fillText("Welcome to the Kule's web site!", 300, 100);
canvas.fillText("Under construction...", 300, 120);
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0wo6f2zm/).

Comment: If you don't want to use canvas, it's much easier to use CSS text-shadow. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow

Comment: Yes, I found it :) Thanks man for everything, and for advice for SO, I am new so I am still little confused.